# element.classList not returning classes added dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom

i have some js code which adds a class **hidden** to a div, but when i try to read classes of that div, element.classList returns only the classes present in html

my div html

```
<div id="someid" class="addendum"> </div>
```

But something weird occurs when i print it on console, i can actually see the classes added dynamically.
**"hidden"** is the class i have added dynamically,but if i try to print `console.log(el.classList.value)` it returns only addendum.I can only see the class **hidden** when i do

```
console.log(el.classList)
```

Why this occurs? DOMTokenList only shows the dynamically added class in console.

[image]

Comment: trying in the developer tools console => 
document.getElementById('question').classList.add('hidden');
console.log(document.getElementById('question').classList.value);

it works fine -> please post a code snippet of your actual work

Comment: are you adding the class, because classlist returns all the classes?

Answer (score 0):

*DOMTokenList* does not represent the actual value.

If you hover over the little blue ***`i`*** icon, it says:

> Value below was evaluated just now.